# external table bad files

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sql-loader, external-tables

I am using external table for ETL. The access driver creates a bad file which contains records which were bad in some way like data type mismatch. However, constraint violations like unique constraint violation are not written to Bad file by access driver and thus have to be handled in the loading process from external table and put into some other bad file created for this second part of load process. Please suggest some good design to merge these two bad files or handle bad data in a unified way.

Comment: What "unique constraint" are you referencing?  So far as I'm aware, you cannot define a constraint on an external table.  Are you talking about errors that occur when you extract data from the external table and write it to a permanent table?

Comment: @JustinCave - Yes, I am referring to constraint violations that might occur when load it to the permanent table.